# Particles Emitting out of the mesh. Leaving the object

Tags: mesh, particles, weight-painting, origin, particle-edit-mode

I am new to Blender and I am using Blender 3.0.0 and I was making a city scape and I sculpted some buildings and I want to place them on the plane as particles but the building particles are emitting outside the plane.
[image]

and also the particles are submerging under the plane a bit even though the object origin at its base.
[image]

And also the particles are not coordinating with the weight paint. and I want it to coordinate with weight paint desperately.

Here is the blender file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XpTrFCb3NUI797dO8dt1qX9GR5jjHMX2/view?usp=sharing

Edit:- Just now I realized that the plane face was wrong side so I flipped it but it didnt solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin needs to be at the base of the particle object. If I select one of your particle object, here is what we can see, it's not the case:

[image]

Also you have a *Clip* problem, in the *N panel > View > Clip End*, lower down the value to 100000 m for example.